# Break down Lambda functions by Request Count and Costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

On my AWS account, I have multiple lambda functions. When lambda costs go up, I'm unable to identify which lambda is to blame. How can I monitor each lambda function by determining the cost and request count for a single lambda function?

Answer (score -1):

[AWS Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) allows you to view your costs and usage trends and you can filter by service, function name, and resource ID.

Choose "Lambda" from list of services and select "Function name" from the "Group by" dropdown menu.

Cost Explorer is more suited if all the Lambda functions are appropriately tagged. [This article](https://faun.pub/getting-a-handle-on-spiralling-aws-lambda-cost-in-15-sec-640c49319ea4) explores some methods to keep an eye on individual lambda functions's cost.

Comment: My cost explorer doesn't have `Function Name` and `Resource ID` as filters. Are those Cost Allocation Tags you've configured manually? If yes, you should add that.